# Getting ReferenceError: "OAuth1" is not defined when migrating from OAuthConfig

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm receiving a

> ReferenceError: "OAuth1" is not defined.

when trying to migrate my code from OAuthConfig. Is there a library I need to invoke in Resources->Libraries?

The example code I used is the one from [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/migration/oauth-config)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find an official-looking OAuth1 implementation [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth1)

The project ID to use is in the description:

> Mb2Vpd5nfD3Pz-_a-39Q4VfxhMjh3Sh48

Hope it'll help those migrating their applications.

Comment: oauth1 for google services is shut down. migrate to the oauth2 library. https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2

Comment: Thanks Zig, However, according to a blogspot article, I still need to use OAuth1 for Twitter integration: 
http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/changes-to-oauth-in-apps-script.html